# How do I get italic texts figures in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, context-mkii

Inside an italic section I want to place text figures (which should be italic as well). How do I achieve this? (The document is in ConTeXt MKII.)

Both of the following examples produces non italic (regular) text figures:

```
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\os 17}:{\os 52}.}
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\em \os 17}:{\em \os 52}.}
```

Here are two tests with images:

## Test 1

```
\setupbodyfont [10pt]
\starttext
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\os 17}:{\os 52}.}
\stoptext
```

**ConTeXt (PDFTeX):**

[image: Pdftex]

**ConTeXt (LuaTeX)**:

[image: Luatex]

## Test 2

```
\setupbodyfont [10pt]
\starttext
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\em \os 17}:{\em \os 52}.}
\stoptext
```

**ConTeXt (PDFTeX):**

[image]

**ConTeXt (LuaTeX)**:

[image]

Comment: Does the font you are using have italic oldsttyle glyphs?

Comment: Works for me with the antpolt (Antykwa Półtawskiego) font.

Comment: @Aditya Guess it's **Latin modern** (if that is the standard in mkii), added examples in my question. Took for granted it would have italic text figures?

Comment: `\em` is a command for emphasising text relative to its context, in particular `\em` inside `\em` will produce roman.  If you want to definitively switch to italic use `\it` instead.

Comment: If I run `context` on your examples then `mkiv` is used and the `otf` version of the latin modern fonts are used, and I get italic old style numbers.  On the other hand if I run the older `texexec` command, then `mkii` is used and `.pfb` files for latin modern are loaded.  Perhaps these don't have the required glyphs or `mkii` calls oldstyle numbers in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that `\em` is a command for emphasising text relative to its context, so `{\em a {\em b} c}` in upright text prints `a` and `c` in italics, but `b` upright.  Thus the coding

```
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\em \os 17}:{\em \os 52}.}
```

will be expected to print `17` and `52` in an upright font.

Now what `\os` actually does depends on what version of context you run on the file.  Consider

```
\setupbodyfont [10pt]
\starttext
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\os 17}:{\os 52}.}
{\em Poppy Heavy with Seed. Video, {\em \os 17}:{\em \os 52}.}
\stoptext
```

To get mkii behaviour use the command `texexec`.  This uses the `pdftex` engine and Latin Modern fonts in their `.pfb` version

[image: mkii sample]

You can see this information in the log file, which includes:

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=cont-en 2013.7.18)  14 AUG 2013 08:27
> ...
> ConTeXt  ver: 2013.04.09 10:38 MKII  fmt: 2013.7.18  int: english/english
> ...
> {/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-mathit.enc}{/usr/lo
> cal/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}</usr/local/texlive/20
> 13/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmmi10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-d
> ist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/t
> ype1/public/lm/lmro10.pfb>
> ```

On the other hand if you run the command `context` on the file then you get mkiv behaviour, the engine used is `luatex` and the Latin Modern fonts are loaded in their `.otf` version

[image: mkiv output]

The log file contains:

> ```
> ConTeXt  ver: 2013.05.28 00:36 MKIV current  fmt: 2013.8.14  int: english/english
> ...
> mkiv lua stats  > loaded fonts: 3 files: latinmodern-math.otf (experimental), lmroman10-regular.otf, lmromanslant10-regular.otf
> ```

Thus you see that (a) different engines use different underlying formats and different font mechanisms and (b) it is the mkiv behaivour that gives italic old style figures in the one place expected, mkii does not produce this (at least for the latin modern fonts).